# "Show" Segue made from dragging button to view controller throws error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here's what I did: I control dragged from the button to the `viewController` and starting the app is fine. However, when I click the "let's get started" button, which should segue into the next part of the app, I just get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Latest version of `xcode` (not beta) and code I wrote (I didn't write any code for the `segue` though) was in `swift`.

[image: What the storyboard looks llike]

[image: Part of the error message]

Also, the error message I'm getting

```
Registration for remote notification failed with error: REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION
2016-07-28 14:20:53.108 TouchLogin[6368:503476] -[TouchLogin.BWWalkthroughPageViewController GetStarted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8cc351b360
2016-07-28 14:20:53.111 TouchLogin[6368:503476] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TouchLogin.BWWalkthroughPageViewController GetStarted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8cc351b360'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010132bd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103310deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101334d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010127acfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010127a8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101d96a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000101f09e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000101f0a143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000101f09263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010227ec52 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10279
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000101e0948e -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000101e0a6c4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000101db5dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000101d8f553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101251301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010124722c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001012466e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001012460f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010496dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000101d94f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    20  TouchLogin                          0x0000000100fa6cc2 main + 114
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010437192d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Does your BWWalkthroughPageViewController have a method called GetStarted?

Comment: some where calling "GetStarted" method but it has not found in your code.

Comment: see the error message "..unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8cc351b360..". It appears to be wrong spelling of invoking method or other words you invoke method that does not exist.

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote that's related to this?